# Add message with ShareLinkContent in Facebook sdk?

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-sdk-4.0

Is there a way to add message to the ShareDialog when using ShareLinkContent in android application. Using Facebook sdk 4.0. I am using this code

```
  ShareLinkContent linkContent = new ShareLinkContent.Builder()

                        .setContentTitle("XXXXX")
                        .setContentDescription(
                                "XXXXX in real time")
                        .setContentUrl(Uri.parse("http://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=" + getApplicationContext().getPackageName()))
                        .build();



                shareDialog.show(linkContent);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there's no message property on ShareLinkContent because it's supposed to represent the content itself (i.e. the link), and not what the user's message would be.

If you use the Graph API directly to post with publish_actions permissions, then you can attach a message to the ShareApi class.

If you use the ShareDialog class, then the user is prompted to type in a message, and you won't have the ability to set one.

Answer (score 2):

Use:

```
ShareLinkContent content = new ShareLinkContent.Builder()
 .setContentUrl(yourUrl)
 .build();

ShareApi shareApi = new ShareApi(content);
shareApi.setMessage(message);
shareApi.share(facebookCallback);
```